# On 18.04, installation of ttf fonts fails

Tags: fonts

On 18.04: when I do `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` & say Yes to the EULA question, it fails:

```
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe
  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=netix.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 87.121.121.2 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/arial32.exe  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=netix.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 87.121.121.2 443]
E: Download Failed
```

Comment: @user68186: doesn't appear to be the same error. Am I correct in stating that the problem is with Sourceforge?

Comment: Some of the answers to the question I linked above tells you how to directly download the `exe` file and extract the contents manually. It may very well be a a change in Sourceforge. If it is, the maintainer of the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` has to update the code to fix the problem. However, that would be a bug-report for that package. Bug reports are off topic here as well.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: It works fine with me on 18.04. No error with `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, installed properly.

Comment: @VeeJay The question is off-topic if the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @VeeJay: it worked for me on 18.04 when I used it last year (June I think).

Answer (score 3):

`howefield` on Ubuntu Forums, provided answer:
Create a folder in `~/home` called `mscorefonts` and download the fonts from : 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/files/the%20fonts/final/
and store them in the `/home/$USER/mscorefonts` folder that you created earlier, then run..

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

You should be prompted to give the path for the downloaded files and the rest should be self explanatory.
I then ran

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v" which worked Ok
```